# scala won't take a 12-digit integer

Tags: scala

ok so I'm just getting started in scala.. ran into a weird problem with a large number.

```
import Math._
var num:Long=0
num+=600851475
num*=1000
println(num)
```

that code works fine, yet the following doesn't compile with an error saying the integer is too large.

```
import Math._
var num:Long=0
num+=600851475000
println(num)
```

what's up? can scala not handle a 12-digit number? :/

Comment: Perhaps you should be using a long integer literal (suffixed with an 'L')?  i.e., `600851475000L`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your constant should be `600851475000L`

Answer (score 17):

Even though num is declared to be a Long, 600851475000 is read by the compiler to be an Int, which can only handle numbers in <s>[-2^32, 2^32)</s> **[-2^31, 2^31)**.  Writing the number as 600851475000L tells the compiler to treat it as a Long, which will handle numbers up to about 18 digits.

Comment: Int's range is actually [-2^31, 2^31), but the point is otherwise right on target.

Comment: For precisely representing numbers that even Long can't handle, there is scala.BigInt (in the standard library).  You still can't write 37-digit literals, but BigInt can be constructed from a String, so you can fake it (just wrap the 37-digit literal in quotes).

Comment: @Rex Kerr - Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 11):

Without `L` (or `l`) suffix, the literal's value is treated as a 32-bit int.